# logical equivalences with out a truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We are supposed to show logical equivalences but we are not to use a truth tables to show proof. 
I created a truth table for my reference and I know it is Tautology. My issue is i cannot figure out how to do this without. Can anyone help me?

$ [¬p∧(p∨q)]→q) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$\begin{align}
[\sim p\wedge (p\vee q)]\implies q&\equiv [(\sim p\wedge p)\vee(\sim p\wedge q)]\implies q \\
&\equiv [F\vee (\sim p \wedge q)] \implies q \\
&\equiv (\sim p\wedge q)\implies q \\
&\equiv \sim(\sim p\wedge q)\vee q \\
&\equiv (p\vee \sim q)\vee q \\
&\equiv p\vee (\sim q\vee q) \\
&\equiv p\vee T \\
&\equiv T
\end{align} $$ 
Where $T$=true, $F$=False and I'm making use of the identity $p\implies q\equiv \sim p \vee q$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Recall that "$a\to b$" is equivalent to "$\lnot a \lor b$".

So "$\lnot p \to q$" is equivalent to "$p\lor q$".

Now if you are given that "$\lnot p \to q$" is true, and that "$\lnot p$" is true, what can you conclude?